# AutoScroll event in WIndows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, autoscroll

I have a windows form with two controls, one mail control (Dock = Fill) and a property control (Dock = Right). The property control is set to AutoScroll. It has some expandable panels and if the user expands too many panels the height of the control is larger than the window height and I set the AutoScroll property in order to automatically display scrollbars in this case - this does work. However the scrollbar is plotted over the property controls. The scrollbars of course needs some place but I would like the property window to grow in width as long as the scroll bar is shown (and hence reduce the size of the main control a bit) so that the scrollbar is on the right side of the property control which is completely shown.

Can you give me a hint? Do I need to change some properties of the controls? Or is there an Event "ScrollBarsShown" or something which I could catch and manually extend the width of the property control?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you post your existing code ?

Comment: What would you like to see? I do not have any event handling code, yet since I could not find the right event that is triggert. Otherwise I only have the code that is automatically generated when I place the controls in the designer - would you like to see that?

Comment: The appearance of the scrollbar(s) reduces the client size of the form.  So the ClientSizeChanged event fires.  You surely want to consider reserving enough space for the scrollbar so it doesn't overlap the controls and you won't get the horizontal scrollbar as well.

Answer (score 0):

Put these controls in a `TableLayoutPanel`.  The arrangement should be two columns, one row.  Column0 would be set to 100%, while Column1 would be AutoSize.  The Row could be either.

Then just dock fill the `TableLayoutPanel` in your form.